# AutoComplete functionality not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project that is using ASP.NET 4.5 and C#. I have a textbox server control that is tied to a asp AutoCompleteExtender. The problem is that it seems to either not be connection to the database to there is a bug somewhere in my code. For this I am not using a web service just a simple aspx and aspx.cs code behind. I haven't been able to debug to pinpoint the actual problem yet because I am getting the

> uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection

and am in the process of figuring out what is causing that problem.

Here is my textbox control:

```
<div class="col-md-10">              
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
                MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
                TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
                ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">
            </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="StudentID" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The student ID field is required." />
        </div>
```

And I have the AJAX directive on the declared on the aspx page aswell:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And this is the code behind that implements the functionality for the AutoComplete:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SearchStudent : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> SearchStudents(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Fname from Student_Registration_Form where " +
                "Fname like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                List<string> students = new List<string>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        students.Add(sdr["Fname"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                return students;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

The issue which caught my attention is: You are calling wrong method in your Autocomplete extender

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"

public static List<string> SearchStudents(string prefixText, int count)
    {
```

Here you can see you have passed SearchCustomers as ServiceMehtod but in your page you are using SearchStudents.

Recently I have tried twitter's TypeAhead autocomplete plugin which is easy and fast as compare to Autocomplete Extender. Have a look you might like : 
**[Textbox autocomplete using twitter typeahead in asp .net](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Twitter-TypeAhead-Example-with-database-in-asp-ne)**

Answer (score 0):

[I think you have used this link for your reference .But it worked for me.][1]

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.UI;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
       using System.Configuration;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;
       using System.Web.UI;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
       using System.Collections;

      namespace AutoComplete
       {
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select LoginName from Users where " +
                    "LoginName like @SearchText + '%'";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    List<string> students = new List<string>();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            students.Add(sdr["LoginName"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    return students;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

ASPX Code:

```
  <table style="margin-top: 40px; color: White">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Search County
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Web.Config

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="Default" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;uid=sa;pwd=123;connection reset=false;connection lifetime=1000000;enlist=true;min pool size=1;max pool size=1000000"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And Don't Forgot to create table and insert some records in SQL Server